# Search Option in header. How to handle it?

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

This is the situation:

I have 3 pages, Home/Search/Post

I have a header and the search box is in that header which is **component**. Controller for that header component is SearchController.

So first time user type and search I am calling a search method in thr SearchController which actually returns the Pagereference with parameter(I want the query string) of /Search.page.

But when i search again in the search box, it doent show any search result in vf page. I have checked the developer console, and it is showing the result in it. I don't know what there is no result in second time, it actually display the same result again and again. I am giving my code so that you can clearly understand the question.

**Header.component**

```
<apex:component controller="SearchController">
<apex:form enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<apex:inputText id="searchText" value="{!searchText}" styleclass="text-box search-header" html-placeholder="Search for Blog"/>
<apex:commandButton action="{!search}" value=" " id="search"/>
</apex:form>
</apex>
```

**HomePage**

```
<apex:page showheader="false" controller="HomePageController" standardStylesheets="false">
<c:header />
</apex>
```

**SearchController**

```
public with sharing class SearchController {
public SearchController(){
        queryString = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('q');
        searchText = queryString;
        system.debug('~~queryString'+queryString);

        *All Searching code goes here...*

}
public Pagereference **search**(){
        system.debug('~~search '+searchText);
        Pagereference p = Page.Search;
        p.getParameters().put('q',searchText);
        return p;

    }
}
```

**Search Page** (Same as Home page)

```
<apex:page showheader="false" controller="SearchController" standardStylesheets="false">
<c:header />
</apex>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your issue is the URL Parameter `q` is not being set.  There is no [Page Reference method](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_System_PageReference_methods.htm) like `setParameters()`, but you can do the following:

```
public with sharing class SearchController {
    String searchText;

    public Pagereference search(){
        return new PageReference('/apex/Search?q=' + searchText);
    }
}
```

If this VF Page is used in a Site, you'll need to use your Site Prefix rather than `/apex`.  This is easily done using the `Site.getPathPrefix()` method:

Example:

```
public with sharing class SearchController {
    String searchText;

    public Pagereference search(){
        String pathPrefix = Site.getPathPrefix();
        if(String.isBlank(pathPrefix))
            pathPrefix = '/apex';
        return new PageReference(pathPrefix + '/Search?q=' + searchText);
    }
}
```

Reference:

- [Site Class + Methods](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_sites.htm)

---

### Update

To sort out the issue, let's write out the **Use Case**.  I think the following is what you're trying to achieve:

1. Search text is inputted, and the Component Controller returns a Page Reference to the VF Page `Search` with a URL Parameter `q` containing necessary data.
2. In the Controller for `Search`, it checks if there is any data in the URL Parameter `q`, and if so, it "performs the the search" and gathers relevant data to display on the VF Page.

(1) is achieved with above, so for (2), make sure `Search` is properly getting the `q` URL Parameter and then properly executing the search.

Comment: Thank for replying. Actually I have tried this also but its not working, I am not able to figure it out what is happening.

Comment: Check out my update.

Comment: Yes you are right, Now here is my story. When I am at Home Page and perform search operation it call the search method, In search method I am NOT performing the search operation, rather than this I actually redirect to Search page with parameter in URL.
eg. 
https://c.ap1.visual.force.com/apex/Search?q=Group+By+in+apex
Now the constructor comes in the execution, it checks the url parameter and perform the search and display the result.

IF I move my searching in search method I gets ?q=null because at that time NO url param. I don't know how to handle this, I need url parameter + search result

Comment: So, the `Search` page's controller looks for a Url Parameter and performs the search based on the parameter given. The next step would be to make sure the `Home` page component sends a "proper" Url Parameter.  What does the `Search` controller do if `q == null`?  As well as the other possibilities.  It might help by writing a static method in the `Search` controller that generates the Url Parameter based on a String input, and then you just call that method in the `Home` page controller.  That way you always get a proper Url Parameter

Comment: Correct.. Now its working

                    
Thanks @amator